# 2nd monitor not detected since a freeze fixed by pulling cable

Tags: kubuntu, hardware, 19.10, monitor

```
Operating System: Kubuntu 19.10
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.3
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.67.0
Qt Version: 5.12.4
Kernel Version: 5.3.0-40-generic
OS Type: 64-bit
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz
Memory: 15,5 GiB of RAM
```

My laptop froze. Though I could move the cursor around, absolutely no other input worked. I had to pull cable and restart it.

After the restart, the external monitor could not be seen anymore. It's a Philips 243s5ldab connected via HDMI. The GPU's nvidia 1050Ti.